# NoSql Crash Course/Tutorial

Tags: nosql

I've seen NoSQL pop up quite a bit on SO and I have a solid understanding of **why** you would use it (from here, Wikipedia, etc).  This could be due to the lack of concrete and uniform definition of what it is (more of a paradigm than concrete implementation), but I'm struggling to wrap my head around how I would go about designing a system that would use it or how I would implement it in my system.  I'm really stuck in a relational-db mindset thinking of things in terms of tables and joins...

At any rate, does anybody know of a crash course/tutorial on a system that would use it (kind of a "hello world" for a NoSQL-based system) or a tutorial that takes an existing "Hello World" app based on SQL and converts it to NoSQL (not necessarily in code, but just a high-level explanation).

Comment: I really liked this [video](http://web.archive.org/web/20130106031559/http://www.10gen.com/presentations/webinar-managing-social-content-mongodb). Is a webinar by 10Gen. It explains how to publish basic content and add social interactions (tags, comments, data aggregation) using MongoDB.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Here is a decent slide show](http://www.slideshare.net/drumwurzel/intro-to-mongodb) introducing MongoDB. I think some of the big differences is that most of the systems rely on Active Record or some similar database abstraction.

Also I found a wonderful [free orlys book on Couch DB here](http://books.couchdb.org/relax/), which is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 53):

At its most basic form NoSQL is really no more than a way of storing objects using some sort of key/value pairing system. You use this all the time already I assume. For instance. in javascript you can create an object named foo and then do `foo['myobj'] = myobj;` to store stuff in the object.

All NoSQL servers really do is give you a way to add/delete/query massive arrays and still allow for persistence and fault tolerance. You can create a NoSQL in memory server in about 100 lines of code.

So let's do it this way...in CouchDB you use map/reduce...so let's create a map function do to the same as a bit of SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE age > 10
```

In CouchDB you provide the server with a JavaScript function that gets run against every item in the database...

```
function (doc)
{
    if (doc.objType == "users") {
       if (doc.age > 10) {
           emit(doc._id, null)
       }
    }
}
```

That's all there really is to it.....it gets way more complex from there on the server end, as the server has to handle crashes, and multiple revisions of the same object, but this is just an example.

Comment: Your example seems like it would be inefficient in a big DB. Can the server index on doc type or be smart about the keys it uses and index on the keys?  Like keys could be user1, user2, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=163) video from DNR TV, doing some hands on with [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). Might be nice for a first introduction.

Answer (score 2):

mongoDB website provides a great 10-step tutorial in a form of online mongoDB shell simulation. it takes 10 minutes to complete and is a really great way to get started with noSQL!

http://www.mongodb.org/ (click "try it out")

Comment: just to add on this they have a sql to mongo page that helps get the concept through code
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Answer (score 1):

y_serial is written as a single Python module which reads like a working tutorial and includes many tips and references: http://yserial.sourceforge.net/

This takes the perspective of how to persist an arbitrary Python object (e.g. a dictionary data structure) in a "NoSQL" (Not only SQL) manner.

Answer (score 1):

There is one on Infoq [Graph Databases, NOSQL and Neo4j](http://www.infoq.com/articles/graph-nosql-neo4j)

Answer (score 1):

If you like Neo4j see this cool [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/andres_taylor/graph-database-super-star-8079303)

Answer (score 1):

An excellent tutorial on CouchDB: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-couchdb/

Answer (score 0):

Here are my NoSQL Resources:

Beginners tutorial for nosql: http://www.tutorialindustry.com/nosql-tutorial-for-beginners

for MongoDB: http://www.tutorialindustry.com/mongodb-tutorial-for-beginners

for CouchDB: http://www.tutorialindustry.com/couchdb-tutorial-for-beginners

for Redis: http://www.tutorialindustry.com/redis-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: That site is gone, all 404s...

Comment: Yes, this is all 404s.